# Refrescar contenido de un div con jquery pero con infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas tardes estoy haciendo una web de venta de productos, tienen ahora mismo como unas 700 referencias. La parte de la web que contiene los productos se actualiza cada X segundos, ya que si una persona añade un producto al carrito a las otras le salen ese producto como reservado.

Ante esto lo que hice fue un simple función que cada X segundo el div que contiene los productos se actualicen.

Mi problema viene ahora, al ser muchos productos queria hacer un infinite scroll para ir haciendo la carga de 20 productos en 20 productos.

Pero claro si hago scroll y se actualiza el div, el scroll infinite me hace ir arriba de nuevo.

No se si existe otro modo de actualizar una zona que sea compatible con el infinite scroll o bien otra forma de hacer que cargue los productos de 20 en 20.

**Mi función básica para ir recargando el div**

```
(function($) {
  var fnConsulta = function(){
    $(".zona_productos").load(location.href + " .zona_productos");
  };
  fnConsulta();
  timerConsulta = setInterval(function(){          
    fnConsulta();
  }, 10000);
})(jQuery);
```

---

Otra idea que se me ocurre es que cuando actualice el div intentar mantener el scroll en la posición en la que esta antes de actualizar.

---

Public por ejemplo como puedo obtener los productos por AJAX y con infinite scroll. Pero de este modo no hay forma de hacer que si una persona reserva un producto le salga a otra en su navegador.

**Controlador**

```
$productos = Productos::with('etiqueta', 'subCat', 'categoria')->whereIn('estado', [1,2])->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->paginate(10);
if($request->ajax()){
  $view = view('data', compact('productos'))->render();
  return response()->json(['html'=>$view]);
}
return view('index')->with(["categorias" => "productos" => $productos]);
```

**En mi vista**

```
 <section class="zona_productos">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row grid" id="mygrid">
            @include('data') //En este include esta la iteración de cada producto
        </div>  
        <div class="ajax-load" style="display: none;">Cargando productos</div> 
    </div>
 </section>

function loadMoreData(page)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: '?page=' + page,
        type: 'get',
        beforeSend: function()
        {
            $('.ajax-load').show();
        }
    })
    .done(function(data){
        if(data.html == ""){
            $('.ajax-load').html("No hay productos");
            return;
        }
        $('.ajax-load').hide();
        $('#mygrid').append(data.html);
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR,ajaxOptions,thrownError){
        alert("No respuesta");
    });

}
var page = 1;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()){
        page++;
        loadMoreData(page);
    }
});
```

Comment: Creo que el problema que tienes es que usas load para recargar el div, si en lugar de eso usas ajax, el div no se cargará de nuevo, solo tendrás que añadir manualmente los nuevos productos y si no me equivoco, no te hará el scroll.

Comment: probaste usando intersection observer? Disculpa que no pueda darte una respuesta mejor, necesitamos que agregues el codigo faltante asi podemos probar tu error y ver como solucionarlo.

Comment: Muy buenas @track3r y eso como seria sustituir el load por un ajax?? En su momento probe un infiniti scroll cargando los productos por ajax, pero se me subia el scroll

Comment: Buenas @ElFuturoLlego voy a buscar información sobre eso que comentas, no he podido poner más código, no tengo más por el momento

Comment: La tecnología AJAX es muy compleja de explicar en un comentario, mejor busca ayuda de cómo funciona o replantea tu pregunta o haz una nueva al respecto.

Comment: Realize una actualización de mi prgunta @track3r por si la puedes ver

Comment: Para aclarar: La función `load` de jQuery ES ajax

Comment: Hola @Yussef no se decirte, soy algo nob con esto

Comment: La verdad no prestè atención a *infinit scroll* y como no veo referencia a *infinite scroll* supuse que te referías a un simple scroll porque por allí pones scroll infinite. En todo caso, deberías poner como estas utilizandonelminfite scroll porque no deberías tener ese problema ya que éste lo maneja. ¿Podrías poner o el script completo o la parte de como usas el *infinite scroll*

Comment: Tienes razón, luego modifico la pregunta tal y como lo hago para que sea más facil la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Te pongo una respuesta para compartir mi código de ejemplo, pero no es una buena respuesta y habría que eliminarla una vez hayas visto el resultado.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Online jQuery Editor</title>
<script src="https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $("button#add").on("click", function() {
            $("#products").append("<li id='15'>Producto 15</li>");
        });
        $("button#modificar").on("click", function() {
            $("#products > #1").html("<li id='1'>producto 1 (mod.)</li>");
        });
   });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="add">Añadir</button>
    <button id="modificar">Modificar</button>
   <div style="max-height: 200px; overflow: scroll; width: 150px;">
    <ul id="products">
        <li id="1">producto 1</li>
        <li id="2">producto 2</li>
        <li id="3">producto 3</li>
        <li id="4">producto 4</li>
        <li id="5">producto 5</li>
        <li id="6">producto 6</li>
        <li id="7">producto 7</li>
        <li id="8">producto 8</li>
        <li id="9">producto 9</li>
        <li id="10">producto 10</li>
        <li id="11">producto 11</li>
        <li id="12">producto 12</li>
        <li id="13">producto 13</li>
        <li id="14">producto 14</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Como ves, puedes hacer scroll y cuando añades, o modificas, el scroll no se modifica. Ahora solo tienes que cambiar la función Añadir o Modificar con el contenido devuelto por ajax.

Comment: Buenas @track3r pero eso solo pasaria en un ordenador, piensa que si yo reservo un producto en mi ordenador, en tu ordenador tiene que cambiar sin necesidad de actualizar.

Comment: Para ello debes usar un timmer, la idea es la misma, en este ejemplo solo te muestro cómo añadir filas o modificarlas sin que se cambie el scroll, que era lo que buscas en tu pregunta, si no es eso, cámbiala con tu nueva necesidad

Comment: Y en mi pregunta, tengo una función con la que obtengo los productos en AJAX, se puede poner un timer a eso?

Comment: claro! el timmer se hace en javascript, lo que hagas dentro de esa función puede ser cualquier cosa, incluso una llamada ajax. En tu caso puedes llamar loadMoreData() sin problemas

Comment: En ese caso ya lo probé, no se si tiene que ver algo el que vaya cargando por paginas, pero se me volvia arriba

Comment: Sigo pensando que es el load, el timmer lo tienes llamando a un load que hace el scroll (fnConsulta()), y el timmer debería llamar unicamente al append

Comment: Pero si es un append va ir añadiendo todo el rato no?, perdona que pregunte tanto, pero me da que es lo que ya he probado y no me funciona

Comment: Por eso en mi ejemplo hay append y html para modificar, según el id del producto y si existe o no, toca modificar o añadir, y modificar no hace falta a no ser que cambie algo de lo que se muestra, es decir, si existe lo saltas y añades solo cuando no existe ya.

Comment: Entendido, pues voy a realizar un prueba y te comento, gracias!